# How do i apply to VCLStyle for TLinkLabel

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I tried to apply VCLStyle for TLinkLabel.

Sadly, I can not display underline(sentece of A Tag)

```
TLinkLabel.Caption := 'Sma<a>pl</a>e';
```

How do I solved this ?

To solve this problem, but a tag is not appeared likely this "Sample"
[image]

```
procedure TgLinkLabelHook.Paint(Canvas: TCanvas);
var
  LDetails: TThemedElementDetails;
  ParseStr: String;
  DrawRect: TRect;
  DC: HDC;
  TextSize: TSize;
  SaveFont: HFont;
  ThemeTextColor: TColor;
begin
  ParseStr := ParseLinks;
  LDetails := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tbPushButtonPressed);
  DC := GetDC(0);
  try
    SaveFont := SelectObject(DC, TLinkLabel(Control).Font.Handle);
    try
      GetTextExtentPoint32(DC, PWideChar(ParseStr), Length(ParseStr), TextSize);
    finally
      SelectObject(DC, SaveFont);
    end;
  finally
    ReleaseDC(0, DC);
  end;
  Canvas.Font := TLinkLabel(Control).Font;
  Canvas.Font.Style := Canvas.Font.Style + [fsUnderline];
  Canvas.Font.Size := TLinkLabel(Control).Font.Size;
  if StyleServices.GetElementColor(LDetails, ecBodyTextColor, ThemeTextColor) then
    Canvas.Font.Color := ThemeTextColor;
//  DrawRect := Rect(0, 0, TextSize.cx, TextSize.cy);
  DrawRect := Control.ClientRect;
  DrawControlText(Canvas, LDetails, ParseStr, DrawRect, DT_VCENTER or DT_CENTER);
end;

procedure TForm8.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TLinkLabel, TgLinkLabelHook);
end;
```

Comment: The default text font is used because you call the `DrawControlText` which uses the control's default font for rendering. That's what overrides your canvas font settings. Another thing is that you can't change the link colors to something else than the system colors (like COLOR_HIGHLIGHT) or the default font color of the label, so your attempt seems to be useless, if I get right you want to use custom  link colors. See for instance [`here`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/bd54bd30-e21f-4dc7-a77f-88de02c63f72/).

Comment: You can call `StyleServices.DrawText` instead of `DrawControlText` but nothing changes on the fact the links from the `TLinkLabel` ([`SysLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760706(v=vs.85).aspx) control) are rendered by the system using system colors and if you would like to render them by your own you would have to parse the text again and render each part by your own, what makes the `TLinkLabel` usage useless.

Comment: @TLama, you are right, why no post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @RRUZ, I did, but then deleted, since it's just part of the problem. OP seems want to override link colors, what is not possible without own caption parsing and rendering, what makes the `TLinkLabel` useless, in this case might be better to use an ordinary `TLabel`. The hook paint override for `TLinkLabel` makes no sense here because you will lose the link coloring.

Comment: @TLama your answer will look better if you replace your original answer for the comment which you post, because the key of this issue is `the TLinkLabel (SysLink control) are rendered by the system using system colors` and functions like [SetTextColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has no effect, so the only workaround to change the color (to fit with the vcl styles) is draw the control manually.

Comment: @TLama, Ok now you have my +1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***How to render a label text based on canvas font settings you used:***

Use the [`TCustomStyleServices.DrawText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Themes.TCustomStyleServices.DrawText) function:

```
StyleServices.DrawText(Canvas.Handle, LDetails, ParseStr, DrawRect, DT_VCENTER or DT_CENTER, Canvas.Font.Color);
```

instead of [`TStyleManager.DrawControlText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook.DrawControlText). This function uses the default control font settings, so it simply ignores the settings you've done. On its first line it takes the font from the assigned control, what set the canvas font to the default control's font:

```
Canvas.Font := TWinControlClass(Control).Font;
```

***About your intention:***

Note, that it's not possible to use custom colors for label links because they are rendered by the system. There are only two workarounds to change them, either you can set the system colors used for the link font rendering or parse and render the label caption completely by your own, what makes `TLinkLabel` usage useless.